# Case When with AND?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to use `Case` `When` with `AND` condition and it is not calculating the sum properly.

For example:

```
SELECT DATE(`SubmitDate`), 
     SUM(CASE status WHEN 'New' AND `Type` = 'consumer' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as new_consumer,
     SUM(CASE status WHEN 'New' AND `Type` = 'business' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as new_business
FROM report
WHERE `source` = 'net'
group by DATE(`SubmitDate`) Order by `SubmitDate` DESC
```

Comment: what it is not doing properly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `CASE WHEN [Condition] THEN...` rather than a simple case expression:

```
SELECT DATE(`SubmitDate`), 
     SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'New' AND `Type` = 'consumer' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as new_consumer,
     SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'New' AND `Type` = 'business' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as new_business
FROM report
WHERE `source` = 'net'
group by DATE(`SubmitDate`) Order by `SubmitDate` DESC
```

Answer (score 3):

You should write

```
CASE  WHEN status='New' AND `Type` = 'consumer' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Check the syntax of [CASE WHEN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-statement.html)